# Calculate Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{z^2 - 9}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{z^2 - 9}$

I'm unsure how to calculate the Laurent Series for this. The answer I have says use the geometric series, but I'm unsure how. I know that $\frac{1}{(1-z}$ is the geometric series, but I am unsure how to apply it here

Comment: The Laurent series around *what* point/in *what* set?

Comment: @DanielMcElroy Daniel, would you please provide a point about which the function is expanded?

Comment: @Dr.MV around their isolated singualrities

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+...\tag1$$

---

$$\frac{1}{z^2-9}=\frac{1}{z-3}\cdot\frac1{z+3}$$
A Laurent series about $z=3$ would be $$\frac1{z-3}\cdot\frac1{6-(3-z)}=\frac1{z-3}\cdot\frac16\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{3-z}{6}}$$
This final term can be expanded using the above formula $(1)$. To find a Laurent series about $z=-3,$ you instead expand the other bracket. About any other point, you can use a Taylor Series.

Comment: Okay your answer is better than the one I have. Just I don't really understand how you notice that it should be 1/(6-(3-z)). Like is there a way to find this

Comment: This is not correct.  You have begin developing a Laurent series around $z=3$, not $z=-3$.  And the last statement is false.  There are two poles; one at $z=3$ and the other at $z=-3$.  So, one cannot write a Taylor series around either of the poles.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, the first part of my answer does find a Laurent Series about $z=3$, then I said to find one about $z=-3$ you can write $$\frac1{(z-3)(z+3)}=-\frac1{z+3}\cdot\frac1{6-(z+3)}$$ and do similar, right?

Comment: Yes, one can find LS around the poles.

Comment: @DanielMcElroy It is because you are asked to find a Laurent Series about $z=3$, and so you want a $(z-3)$ term, and so you turn $(z+3)$ into $(z-3)+6$, and then you can expand as the formula $(1)$ says.